# Where mysql stores the password of users

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.1

When we setup a MySQL database system, system automatically create a MySQL databse in which there are multiple tables like `db,event,func,host,servers,slow_log,user_info etc.`
In `user_info` table I can get the list of users and their details by executing query like `select * from user_info;` except password.

```
But in which table MySQL store the password of every users?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL passwords for users are stored within MySQL itself; they are stored in the mysql.user table. The passwords are hashed by default using the `PASSWORD()` function.

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-names.html)

Comment: How to unhash the password and see it? I forgot the password but i cannot change it, it has to be the default one because there are many users using it for Excel sheets.

Answer (score 4):

in the `mysql` db, `user` table

```
SELECT
    User,
    Password
FROM mysql.user;
```

Comment: I have `user_info` table instead `user` in which it doesn't contain password column.